# jQuery - change slider value and save

Tags: jquery, dynamic, slider, edit

I want to write a table row edit/save function, I can check checkbox to add new days to my table rule, and when I click edit button, it will shows the original checkboxes that matches the table rule's day value. Now the problem is, I want slider time can also do that, if I click edit button, it will shows the correct slider that matches the table rule's time value, and dynamically change the time value when people slide the slider, after that, people can also save the new time value. Anyone can help?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cst5vpv3/2/)

```js
$('#sliderTime').slider({
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: 1440,
 step: 60,
 values: [400, 920],
   
 slide: function (e, ui) {
  var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
  var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

  if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
  if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
  if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
  if (hours1 < 10) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
  if (hours1 == 24) {
   hours1 = "23";
   minutes1 = "59";
  }

  $('#time1').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

  var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
  var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

  if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
  if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
  if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
  if (hours2 < 10) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
  if (hours2 == 24) {
   hours2 = "23";
   minutes2 = "59";
  }

  $('#time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
 }
});

var dateVals = [];

$('#add').click(function() {
 var dateVals = [];
 $('#Date :checked').each(function () {
  dateVals.push($(this).attr('name'));
 });
    var Time = $('#time1').html() + ' - ' + $('#time2').html();
 
    var row = '<tr class="myRows">'
   + '<td class="rowDate">' + dateVals + '</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
      + '<td class="rowTime">' + Time + '</td>'
   + '<td><div><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></div></td>'
   + '</tr>';

 $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
 $("#sliderTime").slider('values', [400, 920]);
    $('#time1').text('07:00');
 $('#time2').text('15:00');
 $('#Date :checked').removeAttr('checked');
});

$('#form').on('click','.edit',function() {
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var rowDate = $row.find('.rowDate');
    var days = rowDate.text().split(',');
    rowDate.html($('#Date').clone());
    rowDate.find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if ( $.inArray($(this).attr('name'), days) !== -1 ) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
    $(this).replaceWith('<button type="button" class="save">Save</button>');
});

$('#form').on('click','.save',function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.myRows');
    var rowDate = parent.find('.rowDate');
    var days = rowDate.find(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
        return this.name
    }).get().join(',');
    rowDate.empty().text(days);
    $(this).replaceWith('<button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button>');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <label></label>
    <div>
  <table id="Date">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>Sun</th>
     <th>Mon</th>
     <th>Tue</th>
     <th>Wed</th>
     <th>Thu</th>
     <th>Fri</th>
     <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input name="Sunday" type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
     <td><input name="Monday" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
     <td><input name="Tuesday" type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
     <td><input name="Wednesday" type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
     <td><input name="Thursday" type="checkbox" value="4"></td>
     <td><input name="Friday" type="checkbox" value="5"></td>
     <td><input name="Saturday" type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <span id="time1">07:00</span> - <span id="time2">15:00</span>
 <br><br>
 <div id="sliderTime" style="width:90%"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<table id="form">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
   <th>Table Rules</th>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable to flag when you are editing a a row, then if in editing mode, make the slider update the html of the row being edited.  I made a basic example, but you will need to expand it to get it to work with editing multiple rows:

```js
var editing = false;
$('#sliderTime').slider({
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: 1440,a
 step: 60,
 values: [400, 920],
   
 slide: function (e, ui) {
  var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
  var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

  if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
  if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
  if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
  if (hours1 < 10) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
  if (hours1 == 24) {
   hours1 = "23";
   minutes1 = "59";
  }

  $('#time1').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

  var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
  var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

  if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
  if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
  if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';$('#time1').change(function(){
 alert('hello');
});
  if (hours2 < 10) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
  if (hours2 == 24) {
   hours2 = "23";
   minutes2 = "59";
  }

  $('#time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
        if (editing) $('.rowTime').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1 + ' - ' + hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
 }
});

var dateVals = [];

$('#add').click(function() {
 var dateVals = [];
 $('#Date :checked').each(function () {
  dateVals.push($(this).attr('name'));
 });
    var Time = $('#time1').html() + ' - ' + $('#time2').html();
 
    var row = '<tr class="myRows">'
   + '<td class="rowDate">' + dateVals + '</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
      + '<td class="rowTime">' + Time + '</td>'
   + '<td><div><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></div></td>'
   + '</tr>';

 $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
 $("#sliderTime").slider('values', [400, 920]);
    $('#time1').text('07:00');
 $('#time2').text('15:00');
 $('#Date :checked').removeAttr('checked');
});

$('#form').on('click','.edit',function() {
    editing = true;
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var rowDate = $row.find('.rowDate');
    var days = rowDate.text().split(',');
    rowDate.html($('#Date').clone());
    rowDate.find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if ( $.inArray($(this).attr('name'), days) !== -1 ) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
    $(this).replaceWith('<button type="button" class="save">Save</button>');
});

$('#form').on('click','.save',function() {
    editing = false;
    var parent = $(this).closest('.myRows');
    var rowDate = parent.find('.rowDate');
    var days = rowDate.find(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
        return this.name
    }).get().join(',');
    rowDate.empty().text(days);
    $(this).replaceWith('<button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cst5vpv3/3/

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand ><

Answer (score 0):

**#add** In adding the new value you can get in this way.

```
alert( $('#sliderTime').slider('values') );
```

You have to do, I got to change these new values with the old. Take it easy.

```
$("#sliderTime").slider('values', [400, 920]);
```